# Elasticsearch not starting

Tags: elasticsearch

I updated from elasticsearch 0.17.6 to 0.19.2 and everything seems fine, but I cannot connect to port 9200 locally.

When I watch the es log I see that it's cycling furiously through all node names without actually connecting to any of them.

The logs look like this -

```
[2013-02-01 22:39:41,950][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Hardcore] {0.19.2}[3212]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:41,959][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Hardcore] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:42,559][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Royal Roy] {0.19.2}[3228]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:42,567][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Royal Roy] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:43,182][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Mercury] {0.19.2}[3244]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:43,190][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Mercury] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:43,788][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Raye, Frankie] {0.19.2}[3260]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:43,796][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Raye, Frankie] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:44,362][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Tarantula] {0.19.2}[3276]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:44,371][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Tarantula] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:44,967][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Atleza] {0.19.2}[3292]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:44,975][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Atleza] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:45,529][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [St. Croix, Claudette] {0.19.2}[3308]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:45,538][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [St. Croix, Claudette] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:46,096][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Nameless One] {0.19.2}[3324]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:46,105][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Nameless One] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:46,680][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Donald Pierce] {0.19.2}[3340]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:46,688][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Donald Pierce] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:47,264][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Lexington, Alexander] {0.19.2}[3356]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:47,272][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Lexington, Alexander] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
[2013-02-01 22:39:47,881][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.node   ] [Nightside] {0.19.2}[3372]: initializing ...
[2013-02-01 22:39:47,890][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.plugins] [Nightside] loaded [], sites [cloud-aws]
```

and so on and so forth.

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: In some rare cases elasticsearch prints error message to stderr instead of log before exiting. If you can start elasticsearch manually from terminal instead of using service wrapper or init.d script (not sure which OS you are in) you might be able to see this error message.

Comment: Thats what I wound up doing, turns out it was a cloud-aws configuration issue that isn't entirely resolved. commenting out discovery.type ec2 and the amazon keys (in elasticsearch.yml) let it work normally